# Convert a Workflow formula into Apex code

Tags: apex, workflow

I have a workflow, and I need to convert this into Apex code, could you help me up please?

This is the code i have for now, but i need to contemplate the fact the user is entering the "Intro", and convert it into an space " "

```
map<id,string> mapOld = new map<id,string>();
map<id,string> mapNew = new map<id,string>();
list<Id> changedList= new list<Id>;

for (Opportunity opp: trigger.old) { 
    mapOld.put(opp.Id, opp.description);
}

for (Opportunity opp: trigger.new) {              
    mapNew.put(opp.Id, opp.description);
    if (mapOld.get(opp.Id) =! opp.Description)
        changedList.add(opp.Id);
}

for (Opportunity opp : changedList){
    if (opp.description.lenght() <= 655) {                        
        opp.Description_Test__c = opp.description
    }
    else {
        opp.Description_Test__c = opp.description.subString(0,655);
        opp.Description_Test__c = opp.Description_Test__c.subString(0, opp.Description_Test__c.lastIndexOf(' ')) + '...';
    }
}
update changedList;
```

And this is the formula i have in the workflow.

```
IF( 
    LEN(desc__c) > 644, 
    LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(desc__c, SUBSTITUTE($Label.LineBreak, "-", "")," "), 644) & ' (...)', 
    SUBSTITUTE(desc__c, SUBSTITUTE($Label.LineBreak, "-", "")," ") 
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's much easier with `String.Abbreviate()` (check https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_apex_language_reference.pdf)

Focusing on the last loop of your method:

```
for (Opportunity opp : changedList) {
    String description = opp.description;

    if (description.length () > 644)
    {
        description = description.replace ('\r', ' ');
        description = description.abbreviate (644);
    }
    else
    {
        description = description.replace ('\r', ' ');
    }
    opp.Description_Test__c = description;
}
```

I think that the logic above copies your workflow formula. I left it like that for clarity. In real production code you would use a constant for 644 (no magic numbers!) and you could move the `description.replace ('\r', ' ')` out of the if, as it's present in both cases. That makes the code so simple that you could even remove the if altogether:

```
for (Opportunity opp : changedList) {
    String description = opp.description;
    opp.Description_Test__c = description.replace ('\r', ' ').abbreviate(644);
}
```

You should add a few unit tests to verify that the behaviour is exactly the one you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and what if I need to use the $Label.LineBreak ? I'f a make a test in anounymous, i get error using " $Label.LineBreak"

Comment: What do you need $Label.LineBreak for? What is it? Is it a custom label? Assuming it's a custom label named 'Label', you can access it like this in Apex:  `Label.LineBreak`. However, I don't see the point of storing the line break in a label. The purpose of labels is to create translatable resource strings, whereas the line break is a constant (which can be referenced as the '\r' string literal). It's not like you have a platform-dependent character, given that Salesfore is effectively your platform.